# How do you test a implementation of k-means?

Tags: testing, cluster-analysis, data-analysis, k-means

how do you test your own k-means implementation for multidimensional data sets?

I was thinking of running an already existing implementation (i.e. Matlab) on the data and compare the results with my algorithm. But this would require both algorithms to work more than roughly the same and the mapping between the two results probably is no piece of cake.

Do you have a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See answers of the same question over at [Cross Validated: How do you test an implementation of k-means?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4930/how-do-you-test-an-implementation-of-k-means).